# Comparing two different audio files doesn't work

Tags: java, audio, compare, fingerprint

I want to compare two audio file for example mp3 and wav. I use  [musicg](https://code.google.com/p/musicg/) to compare by fingerprints.

```
Wave record1 = new Wave(music1.toString());
Wave record2 = new Wave(music2.toString());
FingerprintSimilarity Similarity=record1.getFingerprintSimilarity(record2);
System.out.println(Similarity.getSimilarity());
```

musicg work only on wav so I convert mp3 to wav using [JAVE](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/manual.php)

```
    File temp = new File("temp.wav");
    AudioAttributes audio = new AudioAttributes();
    audio.setCodec("pcm_s16le");
    audio.setBitRate(new Integer(128000));
    audio.setChannels(new Integer(2));
    audio.setSamplingRate(new Integer(44100));
    EncodingAttributes attrs = new EncodingAttributes();
    attrs.setFormat("wav");
    attrs.setAudioAttributes(audio);
    Encoder encoder = new Encoder();
    encoder.encode(source, temp, attrs);
```

And now the problem, when I try compare two wav that I don't convert fingerprints work perfect but when I compare two different audio that I have to convert it's always return that both audio are same. `Wave` create `record1` the same spectrogram as `record2` when I give to it two different audio.

Comment: just an idea: i see you are using "temp.wav" - are two files being covered to wav using the same temp file? so that both files are actually just referencing the same file, and it's actually comparing itself?

Comment: thanks man, i don't know how i miss that.. spend 6h+ and didn't saw that easy mistake. I'm blind...

Comment: no problem. i added an answer you can tick :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File temp = new File("temp.wav");
```

both Waves are backed by the same file. :)