# Is there a way to use Java to compare mp3 files?

Tags: java, audio, mp3

How to compare 2 mp3 files for their contents ? If I have 2 mp3 files that I only know their size and length without other information [ title,artist ... ], how to compare their contents with Java ? Right now I can only look at their size and length [ playing time ] to estimate if they are similar, and have to listen to them to decide if they have the same sound, if there is only a few of them it's OK to just listen to them, but if there are hundreds and thousands of them, that's impractical.

I wonder if there is a way to use java to read in the data and compare the sound bites [ pitch and volume ... ] digitally to find how similar they are, if they are 98% similar, I can then listen to them to decide if they are actually the same sound, is there a way to do this ? Also, there is a chance that even if 2 mp3 files contains the same sounds, they may be off by a few seconds, but the rest of the content are the same, so when comparing their data, the algorithm needs to shift left or right to match the data bites.

There must be some existing ways to do this in Java, I'll appreciate it if some one can show me some sample code or point me in the right direction.

After some research I found this article : [Comparing two different audio files doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31603508/comparing-two-different-audio-files-doesnt-work)

And I figured it out, here is my answer [ why put it on hold ?! I couldn't answer my own question, now I have to do it here ! ]

```
import com.musicg.fingerprint.*;
import com.musicg.wave.*;
import it.sauronsoftware.jave.*;
...

public class Compare_Files
{
...
  String Dir_Data="C:/Dir_Data/",Result_Similarity,
         MP3_File_1=Dir_Data+"Song_1.mp3",MP3_File_2=Dir_Data+"Song_2.mp3",MP3_File_3=Dir_Data+"Song_3.mp3",
         WAV_File_1=Dir_Data+"Song_1.wav",WAV_File_2=Dir_Data+"Song_2.wav",WAV_File_3=Dir_Data+"Song_3.wav";

  public Compare_Files()
  {
    Convert_MP3_To_Wav(MP3_File_1,WAV_File_1);
    Convert_MP3_To_Wav(MP3_File_2,WAV_File_2);
//    Convert_MP3_To_Wav(MP3_File_3,WAV_File_3);
    Compare_Wav_Files(WAV_File_1,WAV_File_2);
  }

  void Compare_Wav_Files(String Wav_File_1,String Wav_File_2)
  {
    Wave record1=new Wave(Wav_File_1);
    Wave record2=new Wave(Wav_File_2);
    FingerprintSimilarity Similarity=record1.getFingerprintSimilarity(record2);
    Result_Similarity=" Similarity = "+(100*Similarity.getSimilarity())+" %";
    Out(Result_Similarity);
  }

  void Convert_MP3_To_Wav(String Input_MP3_File,String Output_Wav_File)
  {
    File MP3_File=new File(Input_MP3_File),Wav_File=new File(Output_Wav_File);

    try
    {
      AudioAttributes audio=new AudioAttributes();
      audio.setCodec("pcm_s16le");
      audio.setBitRate(128000);
      audio.setChannels(2);
      audio.setSamplingRate(44100);
      EncodingAttributes attrs=new EncodingAttributes();
      attrs.setFormat("wav");
      attrs.setAudioAttributes(audio);
      Encoder encoder=new Encoder();
      encoder.encode(MP3_File,Wav_File,attrs);      
    }
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
  }
```

Comment: Define "compare their content". Do you mean absolute equality or do you really want to match different recordings of the same song by the same artist(s) as equal?

Comment: Good question, the purpose of the potential Java program is to help me reduce time and effort to eliminate duplicate sounds, so either way you suggested will help, just need to come up with an indicator of something like : EQUAL or SIMILAR.

Comment: You can always open the files, get the content as a `byte[]` look, whether they are equal. That would be absolute similarity. To check the second type of similarity... that is a different story.

Comment: Yes, what I need help is how to read in the mp3 as byte[] and compare the data ignoring volume, two files may contain the same sounds but at different volumes, they are considered equal, any sample code as to how to achieve that ?

Comment: To get the frequencies in a time window, you can use the Fourier-analysis. This gives you the "quantity" of the frequencies. Then you would need to check, whether two tracks at the same point in time have the same frequencies (i.e. the same "sound") and whether their relative differences of frequencies is the same. The problem gets much more compilcated when there is noise in one of the tracks or if the tracks are not of same length.

Comment: Yes, that was the solution I was thinking about, compare how much percent their frequencies are similar within the shorter length of the two, and consider noise as part of the nature of things, with that in mind come up with a similarity estimate : 70%,80%, 98% ... then listen to them to finally decide if they are the same, the Java program might greatly reduce the time needed to find the duplicates. What I have problem is the details as to how to read in that data.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this open-source solution:

http://echoprint.me/start

It's not Java, but you could presumably generate JNI bindings for it.  Looks like someone has already done it for Android:

https://github.com/echonest/EchoprintForAndroid